# SQL Server procedure with drop and insert into

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a trouble with problem as below:

One of my view is very very big and it caused, that refreshing this view takes more than 1 hour. This view is used to a lot of PowerBI reports and it caused slow refreshing these reports. Nowadays day by day I have to use a code below to selecting columns from view and insert into table. Can I do it by procedure?

My code

Step 1)

```
drop table [XX].[dbo].[table1]
```

Step 2)

```
Select
    [productname],
    [productcode],
    [qty]
into
    [XX].[dbo].[table1]
from
    [XX].[dbo].[view1]
```

How to do it by procedure? I want to execute this procedure in a SQL Server Agent Job.

I have tried creating 2 procedures, one of them is here:

```
create procedure proc1 
as
    drop table [XX].[dbo].[table1]
go
```

and the second one:

```
create procedure proc2 
as
    Select
        [productname],
        [productcode],
        [qty]
    into 
        [XX].[dbo].[table1]
    from  
        [XX].[dbo].[view1]
go
```

But if I will start my job with these 2 procedures it isn't working.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Almost surely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) caused by a need for optimization of the schema (and perhaps the query that forms the view). But why do you want to use 2 procedure for what is logically a single "action"? And what exactly does "isn't work" mean?

Comment: We can't help you unless you explain what the problem is. "Isn't working" isn't a good description of the problem. You wouldn't expect a mechanic to be able to help you fix your car with just the information "My car isn't working." The same applies here. This is why you were asked to *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately."* when you made your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need one stored procedure with the logic

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [XX].[dbo].[table1];
INSERT [XX].[dbo].[table1] (productname,productcode,qty)
   SELECT productname,productcode,qty
     FROM [XX].[dbo].[view1];
```

Comment: unfortunately this is wrong, I have a error "Incorrect syntax near 'XX'

Comment: Aside: Intriguing that you chose to terminate (`;`) only one of the statements while letting the other go free-range.

Comment: just a "copy-paste" :-)  Added ;